# Can't have semantic-mode turned on for Python buffers only

Tags: python, semantic-mode

I'm trying to activate `semantic-mode` for Python buffers **only**:

```el
(use-package stickyfunc-enhance
  :init
  (require 'stickyfunc-enhance)
  (add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semantic-stickyfunc-mode)
  :config
  (defun me/enable-semantic-maybe ()
    "Maybe enable `semantic-mode'."
    (if (derived-mode-p 'python-mode)
        (semantic-mode 1)
      (semantic-mode -1)))
  (add-hook 'change-major-mode-hook #'me/enable-semantic-maybe))
```

But I get:

```
Making python-shell-interpreter local to  *Python Internal [792caf12c778150badeeede64c068cee]* while let-bound!
Making python-shell-interpreter-args local to  *Python Internal [792caf12c778150badeeede64c068cee]* while let-bound!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You achieve that by customizing `semantic-inhibit-functions`. From the documentation (<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>`semantic-inhibit-functions`<kbd>RET</kbd>

> List of functions to call with no arguments before Semantic is setup.
>   If any of these functions returns non-nil, the current buffer is not
>   setup to use Semantic.

```el
(defun my-inhibit-semantic-p ()
  (not (equal major-mode 'python-mode)))

(with-eval-after-load 'semantic
      (add-to-list 'semantic-inhibit-functions #'my-inhibit-semantic-p))
```

Comment: I had to remove the not on my-inhibit-semantic-p defun since in fact as the documentation for the semantic-inhibit-functions variable says: "If any of these functions returns non-nil, the current buffer is not setup to use Semantic." => so need to return true to inhibit.